# How to use "uniqueVersion" attribute in maven-publisher plugin

Tags: grails, maven, grails-plugin

I have a grails project with maven-publisher plugin working. It's good to deploy war to a company-wide maven repository, but I'd like to keep only the latest version of a snapshot in the maven repository.

In maven projects, I could do this.

```
 <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        <id>snapshot.mycompany.com.au</id>
        <name>TVL Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>dav:http://maven.mycompany.com.au/snapshot</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

In my grails project, I tried this:

```
grails.project.dependency.distribution = {
    remoteRepository(id: "snapshot.mycompany.com.au", url: "http://maven.mycompany.com.au/snapshot", uniqueVersion: false)
}
```

That didn't work.

When I ran grails maven-deploy --repository=snapshot.mycompany.com.au I got the following error message:

```
Error deploying artifact: remoteRepository doesn't support the "uniqueVersion" attribute
Have you specified a configured repository to deploy to (--repository argument) or specified distributionManagement in your POM?
```

When I didn't use the uniqueVersion attribute, like the following:

```
grails.project.dependency.distribution = {
    remoteRepository(id: "snapshot.mycompany.com.au", url: "http://maven.mycompany.com.au/snapshot")
}
```

It was working fine, although, of course, the repository was keeping every single unique version of war files deployed.

My guess is that this functionality is not implemented in maven-publisher plugin yet, but I thought it's worth checking with the experts first, and see if there's any work around.

Thanks.

Comment: what remote repository manager are you using? Archiva has ways to limit the number of `SNAPSHOT` version very easily.

Comment: Not sure about only keeping the latest, since it should not matter as when used update dependencies they will automatically go for the most recent version available.  But on Nexus you can setup a timed job (like once a day) to prune old SNAPSHOTs you can specify some params.  Look in Administration -> Scheduled Tasks -> Task Type: Remove Snapshots